# how can i download a pdf file from google link using java (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-api

```
package com.example.download;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class CreateJavaFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File>{
    private File file;

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String googleDriveLink = strings[0];
        String downloadUrl = null;
        try {
            downloadUrl = getDownloadUrl(googleDriveLink);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "pdf.pdf");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            byte[] bytes = downloadUrl.getBytes();
            fos.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        if (file != null) {

            System.out.println("downloaded file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error in downloading file");
        }
    }

    private String getDownloadUrl(String googleDriveLink) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(googleDriveLink);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            String downloadUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            return downloadUrl;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Error downloading file: " + responseCode);
        }
    }
}
```

i used the above code but i am able to download a file and if i open manually it shows an error
that the file formate is not correct and file size is also 10 times lesser than the original file(size of pdf was in bytes)

help me out to solve this

Comment: `String downloadUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");` You are saving some header field to file. But you should read the data from connection. Open an inputstream where you read the data from.